# Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g

CREATE TABLE:

```
create table customer (Name varchar2(10), Address varchar(40), Contact number);
```

CREATE PROCEDURE FOR INSERT:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_CUSTOMER (
p_name customer.Name%TYPE,
p_address customer.Address%TYPE,
p_contact customer.Contact%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO customer ("Name", "Address", "Contact")
VALUES (p_name, p_address, p_contact);
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

ERROR:
IT SHOWS: Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FOR SELECT:

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_SELECT_CUSTOMER (
p_name customer.Name%TYPE,
p_address customer.Address%TYPE,
p_contact customer.Contact%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
SELECT Name, Address, Contact FROM customer;
END;
/
```

ERROR:
IT SHOWS: Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

What is the problem.? How to solve it.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

--you need not to put the column in quotes

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_CUSTOMER (
p_name customer.Name%TYPE,
p_address customer.Address%TYPE,
p_contact customer.Contact%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO customer (Name, Address, Contact)
VALUES (p_name, p_address, p_contact);
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

--just use a refcursor to return the resultset

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_SELECT_CUSTOMER (
p_cust_details OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
OPEN p_cust_details for SELECT Name, Address, Contact FROM customer;
END;
/
```

**EDIT** if you want to find details based on name ,then pass an IN parameter and use it as filter condition.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_SELECT_CUSTOMER (
p_cust_name    IN   customer.Name%TYPE
p_cust_details OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
OPEN p_cust_details for SELECT Name, Address, Contact FROM customer
                         WHERE name=p_cust_name ;
END;
/
```

Comment: Hi! i have one more doubt. I am new to oracle. So, i don't know how to create SP in oracle. Here how to use where condition for example. OPEN p_cust_details for SELECT Name, Address, Contact FROM customer WHERE ID=@ID;.???

Comment: @Sesuraj:Please find the edited part of my code ,where i use an IN parameter to use it as filter criteria

Answer (score 15):

1. Whenever you compile something in SQL*Plus and you get "compilation errors", the first thing you want to do is to `SHOW ERRORS`, which will tell you what actually went wrong.
2. Your first procedure has a problem where the column names will not match the column names from your table. Your table definition has `Name`, `Address` and `Contact`, but because you haven't used double-quotes, the column names will actually be `NAME`, `ADDRESS` and `CONTACT` - but your insert statement uses double-quotes, so it tries to insert into `Name` etc. Just get rid of the double-quotes, you don't need them here.
3. In your second procedure, you have a SELECT statement in PL/SQL, but you don't specify where to put the resulting data. You at least need an `INTO` clause, or perhaps do a LOOP over the resulting records.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from user_errors where name='SP_SELECT_CUSTOMER'
```